# Book about a witch that make spells by spelling out words

Tags: story-identification, books, witches

I remember reading it when I was younger. It definitely came out after 2000, but probably before 2010. It was the first one in a series. The main character (young, 12-ish, female) is a sort of outcast because she can't do magic like everyone else that she knows, but only through spelling out words (or something like that).

It was definitely a paperback, but the cover (or at least one of the covers) may have been purple? This is even more fuzzy, but it may have had the character and her older sister together (it's been so long since I read it.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F!  Was this a paperback, hardcover or e-book?  Do you remember the cover art?

Answer (score 10):

I found it (at least I think I did!) It's the *[B Magical](https://www.goodreads.com/series/68022-b-magical)* series by Lexi Connor. Description from the first book, *[The Missing Magic](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/5954115-the-missing-magic)*:

> Eleven-year-old Beatrix just wants to be able to cast spells the way all the other witches can. But when B discovers that magic happens when she spells out a word, the C-H-A-O-S begins!

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. You could improve this answer by editing it to provide a bit more info on the book, such as the name of the author, the date of publication and an outline of the plot, or at least the specific plot details that you described in the question. Feel free to quote text from sites such as Goodreads or Amazon, and please provide links to any pages you do quote text from.

Comment: Also, it'd be appreciated if you'd mark this answer as accepted, which can be done by clicking on the check mark beneath the voting buttons. However, the site won't allow a self-answer like this to be marked as accepted until 48 hours have elapsed since the question was initially asked, so you'll have to wait a while before you can do that.

Comment: I've added a few details from Goodreads.